# Java MVC JSP get Connection and Data from JavaBean

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller, get, connection

I am trying to get the values of List (List productList = data.getProductList();) in ShowProductCatalog.jsp from the JavaBean ProductDataBean.java. I'm getting the error nullpointerexception. I have no idea what is wrong. Please help!

```
      **ShowProductCatalog.jsp**


    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
     <%@ page import = "java.util.*" import="cart.*,java.net.*,java.text.*"%>
     <jsp:useBean id="data" scope="session" class="cart.ProductDataBean" />

      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
    <%
        List productList = data.getProductList();
        Iterator prodListIterator = productList.iterator();
        %>



      **ProductDataBean.java**


package cart;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ProductDataBean implements Serializable{

    private static Connection connection;
    private PreparedStatement addRecord, getRecords;

    public ProductDataBean(){
        try{
            // Step1: Load JDBC Driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // Step 2: Define Connection URL
            String connURL ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/onlineshop?user=root&password=teck1577130713"; 
            // Step 3: Establish connection to URL
            connection =   DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    public static Connection getConnection(){
        return connection;
    }
    public ArrayList getProductList() throws SQLException{
        ArrayList productList = new ArrayList();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM products");
        while (results.next()){
            DVD movie = new DVD();
            movie.setMovie(results.getString("movieName"));
            movie.setRating(results.getString("movieRate"));
            movie.setYear(results.getString("movieYear"));
            movie.setPrice(results.getDouble("moviePrice"));
            productList.add(movie);
        }
        return productList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I realised the connection I'm retrieving in ProductDataBean.java in  getProductList() is null. But How can I make the changes to put the value in?

Answer (score 0):

1. You must check if condition if(productList!=null && productList.size()>0) null and size in jsp then you populate the value.Then return type change ArrayList to ArrayList DVD ,
2. You must set all the values in request including ArrayList value in request then servlet java code add following code, request.getRequestDispatcher("ShowProductCatalog.jsp").forward(request, response);
   In case any issue to comment below this answer.

   public ArrayList getProductList() throws SQLException{
               ArrayList productList = new ArrayList();
               Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
               ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM products");

   ```
           while (results.next()){
               DVD movie = new DVD();
               movie.setMovie(results.getString("movieName"));
               movie.setRating(results.getString("movieRate"));
               movie.setYear(results.getString("movieYear"));
               movie.setPrice(results.getDouble("moviePrice"));
               productList.add(movie);
           }

           return productList;
       }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Found the error. Forgotten to insert mysql-connector jar file into WEBINF lib folder